# Как можно реализовать такую анимацию?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно анимировать движение рычага, который пользователь дёргает на себя (как в игровом автомате). Даны изображения основы рычага и его набалдашника.
Посредством какой технологии можно реализовать подобное? Нужна хотя бы принципиальная схема. Я начинающий и как-то не совсем понятно, как это реализуется.

Comment: рычаг то приложите)

Comment: ... хоть что-то приложите! Хотя бы усилие! )

Comment: это не форум  физиков?)

Answer (score 0):

[svg transition path](https://www.google.be/search?q=svg%20transition%20path&oq=svg%20transition%20&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.5289j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - [первая ссылка](https://www.bram.us/2017/06/21/changing-svg-path-data-with-css/) в гугле.

Переведи картинку в svg (если она такой не является) и дальше по ховеру или клику меняй path. либо чрез абсолют менять движения рычага и набалдашника, но с svg конечно же более правильно)